# How difficult is to find rational points on these genus 3 curves:

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

How difficult is to find all rational points on these genus 3 curves:
$$
(a) \quad \quad x^3 + y^3 x +y^2 - y = 0
$$
$$
(b) \quad \quad x^4 - y^3 + x y + x = 0
$$

Short motivation. Consider the following natural problem. For a homogeneous 3-variable equation $P(x,y,z)=0$, decide whether there is an integer solution such that $xyz\neq 0$. A classical instance of this problem is Fermat Last Theorem.

What are the simplest equations for which this problem is difficult? Let us parametrize equations by degree $d$ and sum $S$ of the absolute values of the coefficients. For $d=3$, the problem reduces to rational points on elliptic curves, and can be solved easily in Magma for all not-too-large $S$. The next case is $d=4$. Then the problem is currently solved for all equations with $S\leq 4$ with just two exceptions: $x^3 z + y^3 x - y z^3 + y^2z^2 = 0$ and $x^4 - y^3 z + x y z^2 + x z^3 = 0$. After dividing by $z^4$, we obtain the equations above in rational variables.

Comment: For these types of questions I suggest that you email Michael Stoll directly. If he can’t do it or has no idea, then it’s probably beyond reach.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao I don't agree on this suggestion. Michael Stoll (https://mathoverflow.net/users/21146/michael-stoll) regularly contributes here, and his (or other's) answers will be interesting to others here too.