# Equations involving sum of fourth powers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Do there exist rational numbers $x,y,z$ such that
$$
\quad \quad z^3 - 1 = x^4+y^4 \neq 0 \tag{$a$} \quad ?
$$
Also, do there exist rational numbers $x,y,z$ such that
$$
\quad \quad z^3 - z = x^4+y^4 \neq 0 \tag{$b$} \quad ?
$$
Equivalently, do there exist integers $x,y,z,t$ with $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ such that
$$
\begin{align}
\quad \quad z^3 t - t^4 & = x^4+y^4 \neq 0 \label{1}\tag{$a^\prime$}\\
\quad \quad z^3 t - t^3z & = x^4+y^4 \neq 0 \label{2}\tag{$b^\prime$}
\end{align}
$$
Equation \eqref{2} looks particularly nice and symmetric.

As noted here [The diophantine eq. $x^4 +y^4 +1=z^2$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61794) and here [Can $x^4+y^4+1$ be a perfect power?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392851), existence of infinitely many integer solutions to $a^4+b^4+c^4=d^4$ implies that $x^4+y^4+1$ is a fourth power for infinitely many pairs of rationals $(x,y)$. Because there are more cubes than fourth powers, it seems that the solutions should exist for both equations, but my search for small solutions returned no results.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something.  Doesn't subtracting (a) from (b) tell you $z=1$, which then says there are no nonzero solutions?

Comment: @Stopple I think the question about rational solubility is for each equation individually, not simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, Peter is correct, sorry for a confusion. Of course, I am asking about rational solutions to equation (a) and separately about rational solutions to equation (b). This is not a system.

Comment: The left and right hand sides of $(a')$ and $(b')$ must agree $\mod 8$, which constrain all of them to be $0$ or $2 \mod 8$. Did you go any farther that path? By the way, $(a)$ implies $(a')$ but looks stronger than $(a')$ to me.

Comment: If $(x,y,z,t)$ with $t\neq 0$ is any integer solution to (a'), then we can divide both parts of (a') by $t^4$ and deduce that (a) is solvable in rationals with $(x/t,y/t,z/t)$ being a solution.

Comment: Bogdan, are any more special cases (but still reasonably general) of your eq's known?

Comment: Wlod, equations (a') and (b') are homogeneous quartic equations with sum of absolute values of the coefficients equal to 4. Currently, there are exactly 4 such equations for which I do not know whether they have a solution with all variables non-zero: these two and the two equations in my previous question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450351

Comment: Would it help to see $(b')$ as $\det\begin{pmatrix}x^2+iy^2&t(z-t)\\z(z+t)&x^2-iy^2\end{pmatrix}=0$ or there is no hope in extending modular groups theory to Gaussian integers?

Comment: Better in Hermitian form $\begin{pmatrix}z(z+t)&x^2-iy^2\\x^2+iy^2&t(z-t)\end{pmatrix}$.